# Activated route missing data when query params provided

Tags: angular, routes

The routing in our application works correctly for normal urls or route parameters. But as soon as query params are used, the routing seems to break. When query params are provided, `ActivatedRoute` suddenly has no url available, and the `queryParams` and `queryParamMap` both are empty (despite there obviously being query parameters available).

I saw this [bug](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12157) filed on Github, but it doesn't seem to apply because even when subscribing to the `queryParams` observable never yields an actual value.

The routing is configured as follows:

```
{ path: 'fileManager', component: FileManagementComponent }
```

And the pages are being routed to in the following manner:

```
<a [routerLink]="/fileManager" [queryParams]="{ folderPath: 'MyFolder' }">
```

We intercept the `NavigationEnd` event and then use the `ActivatedRoute` to do some other configuration (setting up a tab control for the current component). Oddly, the `NavigationEnd` event argument has the correct url, but the `ActivatedRoute` does not.

For example:

```
this.router.events.filter(e => e instanceof NavigationEnd).subscribe(e => 
{
    let a = this.activatedRoute;
    let b = a.snapshot;
    //Here e has the correct url, including query params
    //but b has a blank url and empty query params
});
```

Any ideas on what might be the problem would be helpful.

Comment: Can you add the code where you *intercept the `NavigationEnd` event and then use the `ActivatedRoute` to do some other configuration*? Maybe even build a StackBlitz?

Comment: @R.Richards Added some more code.